# Unable to export specific gpio pins. How to check what uses GPIO pins and how to access register?

Tags: sysfs, yocto, gpio

I use an i.mx6 board (yocto(jethro)) and am configuring a device tree.
I changed a dts file and put the dtb file in a boot partition.
I set GPIO4_IO19 in dts file as follows.

```
&iomuxc {
pinctrl-names = "default";
pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_hog_1>;
imx6ul-evk {
pinctrl_hog_1: hoggrp-1 {
fsl,pins = <
...
MX6UL_PAD_CSI_VSYNC__GPIO4_IO19 0x0000B0B0
...
>;
};
...
```

At first MX6UL_PAD_CSI_VSYNC__GPIO4_IO19 was defined in other group (usdhcgrp) but I commented out them.

After booting, I checked if gpio is successfully determined as I set.
The result is

```
echo 115 > /sys/class/gpio/export
-sh: echo: write error: Device or resource busy
```

So I checked this.

```
cat /sys/kernel/debug/gpio

    GPIOs 0-31, platform/209c000.gpio, 209c000.gpio:
    gpio-10 (phy-reset ) out lo
    GPIOs 32-63, platform/20a0000.gpio, 20a0000.gpio:
    GPIOs 64-95, platform/20a4000.gpio, 20a4000.gpio:
    gpio-68 (ft5x06_irq_gpio ) in hi
    GPIOs 96-127, platform/20a8000.gpio, 20a8000.gpio:
    gpio-109 (? ) out lo
    gpio-115 (cd ) in lo
    gpio-116 (? ) out lo
    gpio-117 (? ) out lo
    gpio-118 (sysfs ) in hi
    GPIOs 128-159, platform/20ac000.gpio, 20ac000.gpio:
    gpio-128 (phy-reset ) out lo
```

gpio-115 is used by cd. Maybe it means card detection.
I want to use it as sysfs to read the state. Any other way to read it ? 
Furthermore, gpio-10, 68, 109, 116, 117 is used by other device.
How can I use them by sysfs?

I think I need to do is checking whether register is correctly set value or not.
If the register value is not the same as I set, I guess the other process set the pin control.However I do not know the way of accessing a register.

What I know about gpio115 is as follows

```
 mux_reg address: 0x01DC and the value.
 conf_reg address: 0x0468 and the value.
 input_reg address: 0x0000 and the value.
```

The same as the other gpios.

How can I access 0x01DC and then get the value in linux(yocto)?

Thank you for your cooperation.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to know the state of the pin, It is already presented to you in /sys/kernel/debug/gpio

```
gpio-115 (cd ) in lo
```

It is configured as an input, and the current value is low, 
This will change if you insert/remove the card in the slot!

If you really want to or need to access the register value directly, try checking up the utility devregs!